# PHP cURL - CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS data is always empty at destination

Tags: php, curl, post

Attempting to make a POST curl request from a WordPress plugin to an external application (Laravel) with a data array.  But on the destination server it always comes through as empty.

```
$ch = curl_init ();
curl_setopt_array ( $ch, array (
    CURLOPT_URL => "my-url",
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "Content-Type: multipart/form-data"
    ),
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array('key' => 'value', 'key2' => 'value'),
));
curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

the post data on the destination is simply empty.  I can hit the end point with postman with post data which does come through successfully.

I've tried using `http_build_query()` around the array, I've tried `json_encode()`, tried different content types, nothing works.

Comment: You haven't uploaded any file for multipart?

Comment: no, no files in my request

Comment: Ok, so change content-type header to `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` as multipart is for sending files.

Comment: Instead of `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST'`, you can do `CURLOPT_POST => true`

Comment: @nice_dev tried changing the content type but the data is still empty.

Comment: is the endpoint https? Does the endpoint expect url-encoded POST data?

Comment: When you say data is empty, do you mean at the receiving end or at the sending end? Also, have you echoed `curl_exec ($ch);` ? `https` endpoint could be another problem as the TLS handshake could have errored out.

Comment: the end point will be https yes, but I have a http endpoint set up locally and neither are working.  It doesn't expect url encoded data.  I have tried with `http_build_query()` method either way.

Comment: Should also mention I am attempting to make this request from WordPress.  I have also tried using their `wp_remote_post` method with exactly the same result.

Comment: I'm having the same problem too. It was working just fine before. But after changing the server to prod, seems like the same code doesn't work anymore. I managed to use `http_build_query()` when there aren't any file in the `POST`; unable to do so when there's file involved.